# KVM clipboard sharing with client running Wayland

Tags: kvm, clipboard, wayland, spice

I have Fedora 35 installed as a VM, with `Qemu/KVM` as the hypervisor and `virt-manager` as the graphical front-end, running under Manjaro KDE.

Following numerous guides & answers I have managed to get clipboard sharing to work between the host and client using the `spice` display server and `spice-vdagent` on the client. However this only seems to work when the client logins to the X11 session. I have found [a Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/swaywm/comments/pg0rqi/clipboard_sharing_using_spicevdagent_not_working/) which claims `spice-vdagent` only supports the X11 clipboard, which is uncorroborated but so far agrees with my testing.

Here's the systemd journals when I login to X11/Wayland on the VM respectively:

```
> journalctl -b -u spice-vdagentd*
## timestamps & hostname removed

## X11
spice-vdagentd[1078]: opening vdagent virtio channel
spice-vdagentd[1078]: Set max clipboard: 104857600
spice-vdagentd[1078]: Set max clipboard: 104857600

## Wayland
spice-vdagentd[1070]: Error getting owner UID for pid 1063: No such process
spice-vdagentd[1070]: UID mismatch: UID=1000 PID=1063 suid=4294967295
```

So my question is: is it true that `spice-vdagent` does not yet support Wayland clipboard? If false, what could be going wrong? If true, are there currently any good workarounds (except for the obvious "don't use Wayland")?

Comment: I have the same problem as you. I'm running Debian on a VM using UTM on MacOS. Clipboard sharing does work between MacOS and Gnome (Wayland) because Mutter (Gnome's WM) handles both x11 and Wayland clipboard back ends and unifies them. However, clipboard sharing does not work between MacOS and Sway (my WM of choice) because it doesn't do what Mutter does. It would be nice to see proper Wayland support added to `spice-vdagent` because I don't think a solution will come from Sway's side. I don't think is Sway's problem but `spice-vdagent`'s instead.

Comment: I've searched far and wide and I've found no answers to this.